# Unable to login using ssh in emr instance

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am new to AWS and I have aws educate account. I have created EMR instance, I have also enabled 22 ssh port in inbound since I am using windows I have also set rdp(3389) inbound rule as well. When I try to connect to the instance using putty. I get error Network connection: Connection timed out. I have disabled my firewall as well.

Does it have to do anything with aws educate account. I don't own iam account. I then created the IAM user, but still I have problem connecting to it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you mean that you created an EMR job flow with a single instance?

Comment: @jordanm I created EMR cluster by going to emr page with number of instances = 3 1 master and 2 slave, with software configuration emr5-31.0. I do not know if this is a job flow. I just created instance and was trying to log in using ssh. I basically just wanted to run my scala application using movielens data as I am learning spark.

Comment: With EMR "cluster" and "job flow" are terms that can more or less be used interchangeably. Is it the master that you are trying to SSH to? When you say you enabled 22 inbound, are you referring to the security group? Is the EMR cluster in a private subnet?

Comment: @jordanm Yes I am trying to ssh in the master. Yes 22 inbound is for security group.  No it is not private subnet,  as I see destination of 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: If you create an EMR cluster, usually the only thing you need to make sure you have port 22 allowed (you say you have). You may try to chek the [troubleshooting guide](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-linux-ssh-troubleshooting/). As well make sure are allowed to connect to outbound port 22 (many school or company networks prevent that)

Comment: 0.0.0.0 is the target for the security group rule. It's unrelated to the subnet. Check which subnet ID is assigned to the cluster, then view the subnet under the VPC section to see if it has "automatically assign public IP" set to true or not. If it's set to false, it's a private subnet and not directly accessible over the internet.

Comment: @jordanm It is set to true. I tried ssh from linux from virtualbox and I am able to connect to the emr cluster. Maybe it is windows problem.